# Node.js cluster get master PID

Tags: node.js

I used following cluster code to fork multiple process for my node app.

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  require('os').cpus().forEach(function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });

  cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  logger.log.info('Worker server started on port %d (ID: %d, PID: %d)', app.get('port'), cluster.worker.id, cluster.worker.process.pid);
}
```

the output is:

```
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 1, PID: 606)
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 2, PID: 607)
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 5, PID: 610)
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 3, PID: 608)
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 4, PID: 609)
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 6, PID: 611)
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 8, PID: 613)
Thu Sep 05 2013 20:30:03 GMT-0700 (PDT) - info: Worker server started on port 3000 (ID: 7, PID: 612)
```

There is 8 worker processes but when I checked process using pgrep, I saw 9

```
$ pgrep -l node
613 node
612 node
611 node
610 node
609 node
608 node
607 node
606 node
605 node
```

so one process extra must be master process and how do I print out the master process IP?

Thanks

I posted another question related to this one, I think it's might be useful for everyone to look at this as well:

[Node.js cluster master process reboot after got kill & pgrep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650527/node-js-cluster-master-process-reboot-after-got-kill-pgrep)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the master process pid with `process.pid` inside `if(cluster.isMaster)`. IP and port are properties of your app so that would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the master (parent) pid with `process.ppid`.
This will let you send a signal which is useful for reloads without downtime.

For instance `process.kill(process.ppid, 'SIGHUP');`