# Node.js cluster master process reboot after got kill & pgrep?

Tags: javascript, node.js

**1st question:**

In Node.js cluster, I know that if a cluster worker is crashed or got kill, it will auto boot up again with a new instance. But what if when master process got kill, how do we make master process auto boot up again if it got killed or crashed? I tried to kill master process and the entire cluster is killed as well. Is there anyway to prevent this?

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
  require('os').cpus().forEach(function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });

  cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
    cluster.fork();
  });
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
  ...
}
```

**2nd question:**

I figured we can find the master process from process.pid. But without this info from Node.js and looking at the output of pgrep -l node, how do I figure out which one is master process id? Is there anyway that I can tag or name the processes when I fork() it so I can find master process in pgrep command?

```
$ pgrep -l node
1420 node
1419 node
1418 node
1417 node
1416 node
1415 node
1414 node
1413 node
1412 node
```

**UPDATED**

After I apply **process.title** as @fardjad has suggested below, it works beautifully. Here is the results of pgrep:

```
  $ pgrep -fl acl
  1994 acl_api_worker_8 USER=nam
  1993 acl_api_worker_7 USER=nam
  1992 acl_api_worker_6 USER=nam
  1991 acl_api_worker_5 USER=nam
  1990 acl_api_worker_4 USER=nam
  1989 acl_api_worker_3 USER=nam
  1988 acl_api_worker_2 USER=nam
  1987 acl_api_worker_1 USER=nam
  1986 acl_api_master SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you not to monitor the master process in your cluster, because you won't be able to handle `SIGKILL`.
You can use **upstart**, **monit** or **forever** for this.

Regarding to your second question, you can set the process title:

```
if (cluster.isMaster)
    process.title = 'master';
    ...
}
```

See [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_title) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @fardjad. process.title is what I'm looking for to name it. I'm still waiting for answer for my question and hopefully someone can help.

Comment: ic what u meant, so we will use external applications such as forever, upstrat, monit to monitor the master process. Nice. It should work I gues!

Comment: i use forever - it works pretty well. i wrote a script to restart the correct forever process on deploy